# Dynamically constructing a SQL request parameter in mybatis

Tags: mybatis, oracle-spatial

Below is my query

```
 SELECT
  /*+ ORDERED */
  F.*,
  SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) dist
FROM NEW_TABLE F
WHERE SDO_NN(F.LOC_GEOM, SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(-12.1254, 22.1545,NULL), NULL, NULL ), 'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=0 DISTANCE=60 UNIT=MILE', 1)='TRUE'
ORDER BY dist;
```

In the above query the value of distance will be changing. 
'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=0 DISTANCE=60 UNIT=MILE'

So can I construct the request parameter dynamically by adding the value eg., 60 to the parameter using mybatis/ibatis?

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple Oracle concatenation operator "||" answered my question.

Replaced 'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=0 DISTANCE=60 UNIT=MILE'
with the below in the mybatis query
'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=0 DISTANCE=' || #{input_distance} || ' UNIT=MILE'